# JQuery bind function to multiple objects

Tags: jquery, binding

How can we edit the code below to bind this function to both `myLink` and `myButton`.

```
if (section === x) {
    myButton = $("#a");
    myLink = $("#b");
} else {
    myButton = $("#c");
    myLink = $("#d");
}

myLink.click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    showMyDialog();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (section === x) {
    $("#a,#b").click(OnClick);
} else {
    $("#c,#d").click(OnClick);
}

function OnClick(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    showMyDialog();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (section === x) {
    $("#a,#b").addClass('clickable');
} else {
    $("#c,#d").addClass('clickable');
}


$('.clickable').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    showMyDialog();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (section === x) {
    myButton = $("#a, #b");
} else {
    myButton = $("#c, #d");
}

myButton.click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    showMyDialog();
});
```